# Joining in with the chazzan in kaddish

Tags: kaddish

In various shuls I have attended, if the chazan sings kaddish (like the chatzi-kaddish before Ma'ariv Amida on Yom Tov nights) many people in the shul sing along with the kaddish. Is this permitted?

Comment: Why would it be a problem - there are no Names and it is all Minhag?

Comment: @AlBerko Someone told me that it is not allowed. I want to know if there is any basis for it.

Comment: I’ve heard some people argue against this that you need to be able to hear the Chazzan. If I’m not mistaken, Kaddish follows the same rules as other responses wherein you can answer Amen when you’re signaled to do so even if you didn’t hear the Bracha, so that reason doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: The Mishnah Berurah brings that it is considered haughty to sing along with chazaras hashatz and therefore it shouldn't be done. Maybe what you heard was referring to that.

Comment: [similar](/q/13385/170)

Comment: Is this the tune you are thinking of? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMnela4OzPs

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes. It is.